# Second derivative of a function in a manifold

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation

Suppose we have a function curve $\gamma(t)$ on a manifold $M$ . Define the function $$f(t)=\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}\dot\gamma(t)^a\dot\gamma(t)^b$$

Introducing coordinates $x^i$ the first derivative of the function along the curve is
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\dot\gamma(t)^i$$

I am confused in how we calculate the second derivative .

In this lecture [Lecture 10: Metric Manifolds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONCZNwKswn4&t=3494s&ab_channel=TheWE-HeraeusInternationalWinterSchoolonGravityandLight) to express the Euler-Lagrange equation it is calculated like this
$$\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}\dot\gamma(t)^i\dot\gamma(t)^j +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\ddot\gamma(t)^i$$

but in this book [Relativity on Curved Manifolds](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521429080) page 278,  in the taylor expansion of $f$ it is calculated like this
$$\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}\dot\gamma(t)^i\dot\gamma(t)^j +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}a^i$$
where $a^{i}=\dot\gamma^{k} \nabla_{k} \dot{\gamma}^{i}$ with $\nabla$ the covariant derivative.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Is $a^{i}=\dot\gamma^{k} \nabla_{k} \gamma^{i}$ or is it $a^{i}=\dot\gamma^{k} \nabla_{k} \dot{\gamma}^{i}$?

Comment: Actually in the book they have  $a^{i}=\gamma^{k} \nabla_{k} \gamma^{i}$ but they called it accelaration am assuming they meant $^{i}=\dot\gamma^{k} \nabla_{k} \dot{\gamma}^{i}$

Comment: Maybe they have a parametrized curve $x^i(t)$ and $\gamma^i$ is the tangent vector to that curve, i.e. $$\gamma^i=\frac{d x^i}{dt},$$ and that's why $a^i=\gamma^k\nabla_k \gamma^i$. Could it be?

Comment: No $\dot \gamma^i=\frac{d x^i}{dt}$

Comment: Okay, then I think they meant what you have now in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a curve on a manifold is a vector field along the curve.

It's not possible to differentiate a vector field along a curve without using a connection. This is usually left implicit in the covariant derivative.

Hence the first derivative of a curve is the usual one but to take the second derivative we need to use the covariant derivative.